# Javascript library to do autoscroll of a div fixed to left of page

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, always-on-top

I want a JS library which can allow me to build an attractive menu which is always visible to the user on the left side of the screen, approx. to the middle.

Comment: if it needs to be always visible, then you should not use javascript, aprox. 5% of users have javascript disabled. If not, you can use i.e. jquery

Comment: You can use plain CSS `position: fixed` to do this without JavaScript in modern browsers (but not IE6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've asked for a library, here is in **jQuery**.
It uses **CSS** `position: fixed` if it's available, and **degrades gracefully** to the javascript way if needed.

### [[See it in action](http://jsbin.com/aqoqo/17/)]

**CSS**

```
#menu { 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0; 
  top: 50%; 
  /* ... */
}
```

**Javascript**

```
(function() {

var $menu   = $("#menu");
var $window = $(window);
var menuHalfHeight = $menu.outerHeight() / 2;

var updateMenu = function() {
  $menu.css({
    "margin-top": - menuHalfHeight + $window.scrollTop()
  });   
};

var supportFixed = (function() {
  $menu.css({ position: "fixed" });
  updateMenu();
  return $menu.offset().top > 0; // ~150
})();      

if (!supportFixed) {
  $menu.css({ position: "absolute" });
  $window.scroll(updateMenu);
}

})();
```

Comment: Awesome! Just one problem. When I scroll down ... the animation of the tab to the left is a bit jittery. Can this be stopped? I don't want the user to be disturbed by the animation of it moving down.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I am a systems guy with barely any exposure to web tech. and you really saved me a lotta time!